# D3 v4 forceSimulation moves elements that don't collide

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of markers (circles) on a map that sometimes overlap. Using `d3.forceSimulation` to prevent this and it's working but some makers move that don't need to as they don't overlap:

```
      const stationForce = d3
      .forceSimulation(data)
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1))
      .force(
        'collision',
        d3
          .forceCollide()
          .radius(
            ... calculated radius ...
          )
      )
      .alphaDecay(0.9);



stationForce.on('tick', () => {
      // move circles to their adjusted spot
      circles
        .attr('cx', (d, i) => {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr('cy', d => {
          return d.y;
        });
```

}

I have a line, using `d3.forceLink` so I can see here they moved from and to. Quite a few circles move (to different degrees) that didn't need to.

For example, none of these circles (the white ones) ever collide with another one (the grey is the starting point)

[image]

Comment: Your code should work. There must be missing information here, like the *calculated radius* for instance, please share it. By the way, you don't need the `manyBody` in the force.

Comment: The calculated radius is data that is propriatary to the client so I can't share that directly, however, the radius is determaned by range of values for example if `x` is between 1 and 100 the radius is 1, 101 and 200 the radius is 2, etc. A good portion of the circles are moved a fraction of an amount compared to their starting point. I some cases this is a diff between 185 and 185.35693750. It almost seems like if I could tell force to `floor` or `ceil` it would respond to me better.